# Updating multiple columns in Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an app that runs on flask and uses sqlalchemy to interact with the data base. I want to update the columns of a table with the user specified values. The query that I am using is

```
def update_table(value1, value2, value3):
     query = update(Table).where(Table.column1 == value1).values(Table.column2 = value2, Table.column3 = value3)
```

I am not sure if the way I am passing values is correct. Also the Table.column2/3 i=gives error saying `Can't assign to function call` . Where column2/3 are not functions, they're field names. So, how do I update multiple values and why is it giving error here?

PS: I referred the sqlalchemy [doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/improve_toc/core/dml.html)

Comment: Please post the actual stack trace. The error you are getting means you are doing `foo() = ...` somewhere, but your code doesn't actually show that. As it currently stands, your code should give you a `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`.

Answer (score 10):

Multiple columns can be updated using the Session as:

```
def update_table(session, val1, val2, val3):
  session.query(Table).filter_by(col=val1).update(dict(col2=val2,col3=val3))
  session.commit()
```

Answer (score 4):

you can write more generic function which will accept your table object, WHERE criteria and the actual update values. Something like

```
def get_update_query(table_name, where_vals, update_vals):
  query = table_name.update()
  for k, v in where_vals.iteritems():
    query = query.where(getattr(table_name.c, k) == v)
  return query.values(**update_vals)

table = YourTable
where_vals = {'col1': 'foo', 'col2': 'bar'}
update_vals = {'col1': 'foo_updated', 'col2': 'bar_updated'}
res = get_update_query(YourTable, where_vals, update_vals)

# UPDATE "YourTable" SET col1=:col1, col2=:col2 WHERE "YourTable".col1 = :col1_1 AND "YourTable".col2 = :col2_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your previous structure:

```
def update_table(value1, value2, value3):
     query = update(Table).where(Table.column1 == value1).values( { Table.column2 : value2, Table.column3 : value3 } )
```