# Access / update field of a query result by string

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'd like to access and update the result of a query.

`SQLAlchemy` provides this by using `row.field`.

However, I'd like to use a loop which contain the names of the fields that I want to change as text.

How do I update `row.field` when field is "the_name_of_the_field"?

```
row = session.query(...).filter(...)
many_fields = {"foo": "all_fields_updated", "bar": "all_fields_updated"}

for field in many_fields
    row.field = "all fields updated"
session.commit()
```

Obviously, the line row.field throws an error because it tries to access the field "field" instead of "foo" or "bar" as declared in the dict.

> AttributeError: 'result' object has no attribute 'field'

I cannot convert the query result to a `dict()` because it wont be detected by `session.commit()` anymore.

I am running into the same issue when using this command instead:

```
table.update().\
        where(...).\
        values(field="all_fields_updated")
```

because I cannot pass a variable as the "field" variable. I'm hoping to overthink this, but I do not seem to get to a solution for this problem as of right now. Any workaround / ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) to set a attribute based on a string. For example in your case:

```
row = session.query(User).first()
many_fields = {"foo": "all_fields_updated", "bar": "all_fields_updated"}

for key, value in many_fields.items():
    setattr(row, key, value)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick and correct response. After some digging I also found this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805600/updating-multiple-columns-in-sqlalchemy

be sure to update .iteritems into .items but otherwise that code snippet is great.